# How to read, and store API calls/responses in Java

Tags: java, api, mocking

I'm trying to create a Java program, that will allow users to record and store API calls and responses in a NoSQL database. Basically, I want to take in the call name, the parameters, and the response and store that in the database. The intention here is to let users re-use the calls w/ the same parameters by accessing the data from the database, as opposed to making a live API call. Is there a way to listen to API calls on a specific URL using Java, and if so how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand the reason for doing it. But the answer to this question is tightly dependent on the technology you want to use for HTTP client, type of request/response and the NoSQL database and strategy you want to use.
As a suggestion, you can create two data classes, `RequestDummy` and `ResponseDummy` with all the required fields you need and use something like [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to serialize or deserialize them and store them as JSON file with the database to be more readable. Ex:

```
class RequestDummy {
    String url;
    String method;    // (GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE)
    Map<String, String> headers;
    String payload;   // For (POST|PUT|PATCH) use Base64 to encode the binary to String
}

class ResponseDummy {
    Map<String, String> headers;
    int statusCode;
    String body;   // use Base64 to encode the binary to String
}
```

And use them during the HTTP call (briefly to just explain the idea):

```
// Initialize RequestDummy
RequestDummy req ...

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(req.url).openConnection();

// optional default is GET
con.setRequestMethod(req.method);
req.headers.entrySet().forEach(e -> con.setRequestProperty(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader());
byte[] data = con.getInputStream().readAllBytes() // Java9

// Initialize ResponseDummy
RequestDummy req ...

in.close();
```

In 99% storing request and response is a bad design. As a suggestion, it's not a good idea to store HTTP request and response for any usage. They are just for communication, you must store the requested data which the HTTP request built based on, and the generated data from the HTTP response.